# JaxB Marshalling: Circle Error by bi-directional @OneToMany References of an Entity

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, jax-rs, moxy

im setting up a webservice with **maven**, **JPA** and **Jersy(JAX-RS)** as exercise. I got two classes MusicLibrary.java and MusicSong.java. The classes using a bidrectional relationship. 

The Class **MusicLibrary.java** looks like this(shows only the relevant stuff):

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "musiclibrary")
public class MusicLibrary {

 // Private Fields
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="musiclibrary_id")
 private int id;
 private String description;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="musicLibrary")
 private Set<MusicSong> musicSongs;
     ....

     //Setter-Methods
     public void setSong(String songName, String artistName) 
     {
         MusicSong song = new MusicSong(songName, artistName);
         this.musicSongs.add(song);
         song.setMusicLibrary(this);
     }
    ....
```

The Class **MusicSong.java** looks like this(shows only the relevant stuff):

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "song")
public class MusicSong {

 // Private Fields
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;
     ....
 private String musicArtistName;
 private String musicName;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="musiclibrary_id")
 //@XmlTransient // works!
 @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="musicSongs") // doesnt work!
 private MusicLibrary musicLibrary;
     ....

 // Constructors
     public MusicSong(String songName, String artistName)
 {
     this.musicArtistName=artistName;
     this.musicName=songName;
 }
     ....
 // Setter
 public void setMusicLibrary(MusicLibrary musicLibrary)
 {
     this.musicLibrary = musicLibrary;
 }
     ....
```

To **create** and **persist** a new **MusicLibrary** i use this function:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MusicLibrary createMusicLibrary(String descriptionName) 
{
    // create new musicLibrary
    if(getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive() == false)
    {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }
    MusicLibrary l = new MusicLibrary(descriptionName);
    getEntityManager().persist(l);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();

    return l;
}
```

The next function shows how i **fetch a MusicLibrary by Id** from the persistence:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MusicLibrary getMusicLibraryById(int musiclibraryID) 
{
    MusicLibrary musiclibraryToFind = getEntityManager().find(MusicLibrary.class, musiclibraryID);

    return musiclibraryToFind;
}
```

And at least i wanted to **add some MusicSongs to my MusicLibrary**. The function looks like that:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MusicLibrary addSongToMusiclibrary(int musiclibraryID,
        String songName, String artistName) 
{
    if(getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive() == false)
    {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }

    MusicLibrary musicLibrary = getMusicLibraryById(musiclibraryID);
    musicLibrary.setSong(songName, artistName);
    musicLibrary.setDescription("IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary");  //Just to check if changes are saved

    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getEntityManager().refresh(musicLibrary); // added
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();


    return musicLibrary;
```

**FIXED:** The Problem is the "normal Fields" of my MusicLibrary.Class getting saved, that means the **description** of the MusicLibrary.Class is getting **changed**, after **refreshing** my **resource**. But the added Song wont be saved. **How can i fix it??** **FIXED**

I use jetty from Maven and the browserplugin RestClient to test my webservice.
The following **xml-file** is generated **after creating a new MusicLibrary**:

```
<musiclibrary id="1">
 <description>RnB</description>
 <music-songs/>
</musiclibrary>
```

Now i wanted to **add a MusicSong to the MusicLibrary**, keep in mind it will change the description of the musiclibrary for testing purposes. The **xml-file** looks now like this:

```
<musiclibrary id="1">
 <description>IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary</description>
 <music-songs/>
</musiclibrary>
```

Keep in mind, if i delete the Codeline

```
 // from public MusicLibrary addSongToMusiclibrary(int musiclibraryID,
    String songName, String artistName) 
 - getEntityManager().refresh(musicLibrary);
```

**FIXED:** the xml-file will list the song in the musiclibrary, but when i turn off my webservice and start it again and listing my MusicLibrary, it wont show the MusicSong again, so it seems like it wont persist my bidirectional Entites in MusicLibrary... **Any Idea how to fix this problem??** **FIXED**

**I got an Annotation Problem Issue now:**

```
 SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error) 
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked 
 exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. 
 This will cause infinitely deep XML: MusicLibrary [id=1, 
 description=IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary, musicSongs=[music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5]] 
 -> music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5 -> MusicLibrary [id=1, description=IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary, musicSongs=[music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5]]]
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:252)
```

I found a solution to setup Eclipse Link Moxy on internet. I did all the stuff, creating the jaxb.properties file addet it to the package where my classes can be found. Added Dependencies in my pom.xml and still got the same circle Error. That means i did something wrong, but dont know what. Im sad. I use the @XmlTransient Solution then which doesnt fit my claims.

**Edit: Updated Classes.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you raise a question and use the MOXy tag, the author of the library is pretty active on SO.

Comment: Youre right forgot the tag when i redited the post, thx.

Comment: So I may found a theoretical solution by myself, if you are used to work with XmlTransient, just add additional fields in the entity class that contains the XmlTransient-Annotation and set these fields by yourself. For Example: A transient field contains an Reference ID, so just create an additional field and set this field by yourself, after adding the relationship between parent and child. I didnt tried it, but i guess it should work. So you got always the references in the Class-Datatables for the Fields marked with XmlTransient and you can work with the datatables (queries and so on).

Answer (score 1):

It is bidirectional but you are only setting one side of the relation, leaving the other null.  The Song should be saved as it is referenced by the MusicLibrary when it is persisted, but its reference to MusicLibrary is null, and so that is what is put in the database.  When you refresh MusicLibrary, it sees that there are no Songs in the database referencing it, and so creates an empty song list.

In short, you need to set the MusicSong's musicLibrary when you add the MusicSong to the MusicLibrary:

```
 public void setSong(String songName, String artistName) 
 {
      MusicSong song = new MusicSong(songName, artistName);
      this.musicSongs.add(song);
      song.setMusicLibrary(this);
 }
```

Comment: if i do that i get a cycle error Message:"

SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: MusicLibrary [id=1, description=IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary, musicSongs=[music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5]] -> music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5 -> MusicLibrary [id=1, description=IdidUpdateTheMusicLibrary, musicSongs=[music.service.MusicSong@bf3973b5]]]"

Comment: @user2169962: You should fix the errors one at a time. Your question was about the JPA issue, and the answer tries to address it. The issue you put the comments is a JAXB issue. Probably there is some fix for that too. But right now you I think you should keep that one out of this.

Comment: Yeap its a JAXB Problem im gonna try some Solutions with @XMLTransient

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing the List of jars required to do a rest call using a jersy provider. Hope it solves many issues that the current programmer facing right now.

IDE I have used Eclipse Keepler eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64
Eclipse link 2.5.2. the jars must have to be placed in side webContent/WEB-INF/lib
    for a Java EE project. see the folder structure

my **web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

My **persistence.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
      <persistence-unit name="providertest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>de.vogella.jpa.simple.model.Todo</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
                <properties>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
                      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true" />
                      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
                      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="user" />
                      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
                      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
                      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
                 </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

My **orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults> 
            <schema>OWNERS_SCHEMA1</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
    </entity-mappings>

Database I have used over here is apache derby.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj0jJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ2YU.png
```

Comment: IF you want to do jersy rest call with JPA using Eclipse Link follow this one